# La cosa, la he puesto/guardado/metido en el armario/la nevera

Tags: verbos, definiciones

¿Qué oraciones son correctas? ¿Los significados son iguales?

- La sal, la he guardado en el armario.
- La sal, la he metido en el armario.
- La sal, la he puesto en el armario.
- Los huevos, los he guardado en la nevera.
- Los huevos, los he metido en la nevera.
- Los huevos, los he puesto en la nevera.

Gracias por sus explicaciones.

Comment: Hola Jenicek. En este sitio estamos escantados de que la gente haga preguntas. Sin embargo, pedimos que estas incluyan algún esfuerzo por parte del que las formula. Por ello, es importante que indiques cuáles son tus hipótesis, qué dudas te encontraste, etc. De esta forma te podremos ayudar más y mejor. Échale una ojeada a [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todas las oraciones son correctas.

Los tres verbos, *guardar, meter* y *poner*, son similares en cuanto a su significado en este caso.

*guardar* sugiere colocar en un lugar seguro, donde la cosa se conservará libre de ser sustraída o de contaminarse o echarse a perder (en el caso de los huevos).

*meter* sugiere introducir en un lugar cerrado, como un armario, una nevera, un cajón, una caja, etc.

*poner* es el menos específico de los tres verbos. Es similar a "colocar" y puede utilizarse cuando el destino de la cosa es un lugar no resguardado y abierto, por ejemplo:

- La sal, la he puesto en/sobre la mesa.
- Los huevos, los he puesto en/sobre el estante.

Más interesante que la sutil diferencia semántica entre los tres verbos me resulta la **duplicación** del objeto directo (OD), que ocurre solamente cuando -- como sucede en los ejemplos proporcionados -- se antepone el OD completo para causar énfasis o retomar lo dicho por el interlocutor. En estos casos, el idioma español exige que se utilice un OD pronominal:

> A. ¿Dónde has guardado la sal?
>
> B. La sal, **la** he guardado en el armario.
>
> A. ¿Y dónde has metido los huevos?
>
> B. Los huevos, **los** he metido en la nevera.

Comment: (y para más complejidad, cuanto más contraste o énfasis se le da al objeto directo, menos obligación hay para la duplicación)

Comment: @guifa Discúlpame, pero no entiendo tu comentario.

Comment: Quería decir que tener el objeto directo antes del verbo normalmente implica algún tipo de énfasis como dices, pero con incluso más énfasis, no hay duplicación. Del DPD: *5.2. Si el complemento tónico no es un pronombre personal y aparece antepuesto al verbo, también es obligatoria la coaparición del pronombre átono, tanto si el complemento es directo como indirecto […] **La tarta la llevo yo** […] Deben diferenciarse estas construcciones […] de aquellas en que la anteposición del complemento es enfática, contrastiva, en las que no coaparece el pronombre átono: **Un libro te daré, y no dos**.*

Comment: @guifa Tienes razón. En ese caso, el contraste se da también por la entonación. No sólo hay una pausa como en el caso de la sal y los huevos, sino un cambio de entonación. No obstante, me parece que la no aparición del clítico sólo se producirá cuando haya, como en tu ejemplo, un objeto indirecto: *Un libro **te** daré*. No es gramatical decir: *La sal, he guardado en el armario / *Los huevos, he metido en la nevera.