# ¿En qué casos se utiliza la expresión "se pone", y en cuáles "se coloca"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, verbos

Siendo los verbos [poner](https://dle.rae.es/poner) y [colocar](https://dle.rae.es/colocar) sinónimos (en particular por el primer significado de cada uno), es posible usar uno u otro indistintamente, aunque ya a fines del siglo pasado recuerdo que la gente popularmente decía que solo ponían las gallinas... sin embargo, leyendo trinos esta semana, cuando alguien decía que un juez *ponía* una medida de aseguramiento a otra persona, le replicaba otra persona que lo ideal sería que el juez *colocara* la medida de aseguramiento... en parte tiene relación con [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/la-cosa-la-he-puesto-guardado-metido-en-el-armario-la-nevera/20760#20760), pero me gustaría saber si hay un motivo o una *regla* para usar el poner o el colocar en una oración

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colocar es más formal que poner, pero por lo demás, pueden usarse indistintamente salvo en casos de usos idiomáticos específicos de cada verbo como "estar colocado", "ponerse a cien", etcétera. Esto incluye también el caso que has mencionado (poner huevos).

"Poner" es, además, notablemente más común. Según el Corpus, estas son las frecuencias de "poner":

- **Frecuencia absoluta:** 282.942
- **Documentos:** 83.039
- **Frecuencia normalizada:** 815,58 casos por millón

Y estas las de "colocar":

- **Frecuencia absoluta:** 50.089
- **Documentos:** 21.819
- **Frecuencia normalizada:** 144,38 casos por millón

Esto responde a la formalidad implícita en "colocar". Si uno fuera a sustituir cualquier "poner" por "colocar" quedaría... sencillamente muy pedante, en mi opinión personal.

Answer (score 1):

Los sinónimos no siempre son intercambiables, por cercanos que sean. Existen lo que se llaman "combinaciones léxicas" (collocations). Por ejemplo, una gallina pone (NO coloca) huevos, y una persona pone o coloca los huevos en el refrigerador. Existe, al menos en el español rioplatense, un uso coloquial de "poner huevos" que significa "ser corajudo/valiente".

Con respecto al ejemplo del juez, está mal decir que el juez pone o coloca medidas: decimos que "dispone", "ordena" o "dicta" medidas.

En líneas generales, podemos decir que "poner" es más general e informal que "colocar". Esto hace que muchas veces se pueda usar "poner" y no "colocar" (ej. poner la mesa -- set/lay the table). En general, es más seguro usar "poner" y, en algunos casos, será más elegante usar "colocar".

Answer (score 1):

Aunque "Poner y Colocar", son verbos que en español pueden compartir significados en algunos casos y ser intercambiables en otros, su modo para utilizarlos no nos debe engañar, ya que tenemos que tener presente mentalmente cuándo utilizar uno u otro, pues no pueden convertirse en método absoluto de reemplazo ya que no son sinónimos, y muchas de las veces su sustitución resulta un disparate. En este caso, el problema de utilizar el verbo "**Colocar**" como sustituto de "**Poner**" se puso claramente de manifiesto a partir de 2014, donde ciertos estudios ya alertaban de este abuso en varios países de Iberoamérica.

---

A este respecto Soledad Moliner trata apropiadamente el tema y elabora una antología con ayuda de sus alumnos donde se aprecia cómo el verbo "Colocar" ha desplazado al verbo "Poner":

- «Me coloca al borde de la quiebra»
- «A la bebé la colocaron Valentina»
- «Eso me colocó a pensar»
- «Ella se colocó brava»
- «La debo colocar en práctica»
- «Esta tarjeta es para que no le coloquen problemas al entrar»
- «Me colocó en ridículo»
- «Voy a colocar la queja»
- «Esas cosas me colocan nervioso»
- «No pude asistir, porque mi mamá se colocó enferma»
- «me coloqué rojo»
- «colocamos mucha atención»

---

El verbo "Colocar" solo tiene seis significados, https://dle.rae.es/colocar, mientras que el verbo "Poner" tiene 44 acepciones https://dle.rae.es/poner. Por tanto, el verbo "Poner" es de uso mucho más amplio que "Colocar".

En líneas generales como resumen podríamos decir que mientras el verbo "Poner" viene a significar dejar una cosa en algún sitio determinado, el verbo "Colocar" tiene el sentido de disposición u orden de forma conveniente o apropiada.
Así si el verbo "Poner" manifiesta la acción del que obra, el verbo "Colocar" es la intención del que ejecuta. Dicho de otro modo, *Se pone sin orden, se coloca con él*.  De esta manera, el verbo "Colocar" no se refiere o equivale simplemente a "Poner", sino **poner donde corresponde**, como se refiere la Real Academia.

Answer (score 1):

Como caso curioso y especial, dentro del argot las acepciones de estos dos verbos, sobre todo en su forma reflexiva, son sinónimas y equivalentes:

> **Colocarse**: Emborracharse. Drogarse.

> **Ponerse**: Emborracharse. Drogarse.

De hecho, la primera forma está aceptada por la Academia de la Lengua:

> **Colocar**. 5. tr. coloq. Dicho del alcohol o de una droga: Causar un estado eufórico a alguien.

En este sentido, y como respuesta especial a la pregunta, es exactamente lo mismo decir de alguien "se coloca" que "se pone". Y, entonces, de este individuo concreto, decimos que "está colocado", "va colocado", "está puesto", o "va puesto".